# How would a diagram for (ls) look like?

Tags: command-line, process, ls

This is a Diagram for what happens after one has entered `ls` in the bash and executed it:
[image]

the first part shows the situation before `ls` is executed. **Bash** is a childprocess of the terminal emulator **xterm** and they have the same aura, the environment, around them. The **xx** marks indicate, that both **Xterm** and **Bash**, as Father-and Sonprocesses posess the identical set of environment variables.

the second part shows what happens after one has started a new process, namely ls.

1. Bash fathers a childprocess,which is an exact copy of itself,
   therefore I named it **Bash_c** (short for Bash_copy).
2. Then, **Bash_c** is being replaced by the ls process.

I think this diagram is straightforwarded, selfexplanatory, intuitive and non-ambiguous.

However, I have not drawn a diagram for `(ls)`, because I do not know how it looks like, I have a few different scenarios for how it could look like, but here starts the question part: How would a diagram for `(ls)` look like? please draw and comment.

Comment: The details are a lot more involved than that, but yes, running a program is essentially a `fork()` followed by an `exec()`.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the two : fork(), exec(), did not know about "system signals" before, I made the diagram based on a wiki about bash, but they did not mention them

Answer (score 0):

The process hierachy for `(ls)` is the same as for `ls`, i.e. `→ bash → ls`, but if you put a list of commands the the parentheses: `(ls; ls)`, then bash starts a subshell and runs the commands in that subshell. The resulting process hierachy looks like this: `→ bash → bash → ls` (the two ls processes are run in sequence).

You can visualise this by using cat without arguments instead of ls: `(cat; cat)`. The first cat process waits for input giving you a chance to see what's going on using `pstree` or `top` in another terminal.